# Find the next image in this composite shapes pattern

Tags: pattern, visual

Below are seven patterns in a sequence, 1 through 7.
Which of the patterns A through F would be number 8 in that sequence?
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it is

> **B**

Why:

> Composite positive integers are **4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, ...**. Each pattern contains figures with number of edges equal to factors of corresponding composite number (line represents number 2, triangle number 3, etc). The next one is 15, which is 3 * 5 (triangle and pentagon).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer suggested by the sequence index numbers:

> **A**

Explanation:

> Each sequence number is represented by its prime factors, including unity where fewer than two factors are present. Factors are represented with this substitution: *1*: a single line, *2*: triangle, *3*: pair of lines, *5*: pentagon, *7*: septagon. So *1* is represented as two single lines (1x1), *3* is a single line and a line pair (1x3), *4* is 2 triangles (2x2), *6* is a triangle and line pair (2x3), etc. The next number in the sequence is *8*, and the corresponding symbol would be three triangles (2x2x2).

This scheme is maybe a bit less intuitive than the accepted answer, but could be an interesting alternative.